# Using Glide, ArrayLists repeats itself in a ViewPager?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-glide

I am using [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load the images from `Drawable`s into a Fragment containing `ViewPager`, everything works smooth but when I install the Application over again and again then the List of images start to repeat 2, 3 times in `ViewPager` i.e after last page of `ArrayList` it will start from first again for like 2, 3 times and repeat the list, and if i clear the application data by going to `Settings>Apps` then it gets fine, I tried skipping the `DiskMemory` but its still same.

Not important but here is the part of my `PagerAdapter`:

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load((Integer) data.get(position))
            .fitCenter()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
            .into(mImageView);
```

What is the best approach to solve this issue? clearing cache on exit? or skipping both memory and disk cache?

Number of images is really large about 700, but size of images is not much i.e around 30kb to 50kb.

Comment: Show your code, in which you are managing Array Lists

Comment: its simple long list of `ArrayLists`, List doesn't repeat on fresh installation, only when i install over and over again then I think it repeats because of the cache system of Glide. on clearing the app data and cache it gets fine again, what u want me to update in question? just `ArrayList`?

Comment: Does it happen only when you install application again or when you close your app and re-open again and again ?

Comment: Use view holder pattern for inflating your list.

Comment: @SharpEdge only on installing again, not on opening again an again, like if i install app and then view few pages an then view again an again an then reinstall it or push it via `ADB` again an then some of the `ArrayLists` might repeat, so I think this is the cache causing this issue?

Comment: When you re-install an application via adb or update the application via playstore the previous data doesn't get removed. So after re-installing the app are you loading the images again ? Here is a tip, Make clean app remove.. install the app and let Glide load all the images, check its `data` size in app settings, then re-install the app again and again and see if the data size remains same in settings of app or changes.

Comment: @SharpEdge on fresh install after loading about 50 images cache size was 60MB, on 2nd install loading same images cache size goes to 90MB but no repeat though, and on 3rd install and loading same images, no increase in size but list starts to repeat now.

Comment: This definitely looks like cache issue, you need to find some way to clear cache once your application has been re-installed. Since data doesn't get deleted on re-install I suggest you put a boolean check in sharedpreferences, once the app is first time installed.

Comment: before adding data to your arraylist first clear it so that same data does not get inserted twice. Check if arraylist size is greater than zero then clear it

Comment: @SharpEdge can u explain it more in an answer? I don't understand how a `boolean check` would prevent glide from re-caching the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having the same issue.

The `drawable` IDs may change on each compile, that's why we have the R class, and I was testing my debug build, and version code doesn't change between builds.

Glide uses `VersionCodeSignature (see load(int) sources)` to make sure what I experienced doesn't happen in real life, because Play Store forces you to change the version on each release.

So when we change the `VersionCode` Glide doesn't use the old cache and creates new cache for new build.

Hope it helps someone